# To access a node which is stored as a value in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, tree

My node is having list of nodes(as children).
`ref.get(L.get(t)).children.add(N);`
`L.get(t)` is giving my parent node. `ref.get(L.get(t))` is another node which I want to work with.
I wanted to add my new node `N` to children of `ref.get(L.get(t))`. While debugging I can see a node in `ref.get(L.get(t))` but throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
public void CreateNode(Node m,ArrayList<Node> S,HashMap<Node,Node> ref,ArrayList<String> L) {   
    Node N = new Node(m.val,m.data);
    ref.put(m,N);

    if(S.isEmpty()) {
        S.add(N);
    } else {
        Node c =ref.get(L.get(t));          //Showing C as null
        ref.get(L.get(t)).children.add(N);  //unable to access node in ref.get(L.get(t))
        System.out.println(ref.get(L.get(t)).val); 
        S.add(N);
        t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use meaningful variable/parameter names.

Comment: You are not accessing the `keySet` of the `Map`... You cannot get any key this way. Your code looks like C#-naming convention realized in Java...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your method signature, L is a list of `String` so L.get(int) will return a `String`. At the other hand, the keys for the ref `Map` are `Node` objects, so a lookup with a `String` will return a null.
So, could either refactor your ref Map to have the unique String identifier of your Node or lookup by a Node object.